# bound value not updating in view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-bindings

the directive

```
angular.module('myapp')
    .directive('hcComponentBlocker', function () {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'views/hccomponentblocker.html',
            priority: 1005,
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: false,
            scope: {
                animation: '@'
            },
            controller: 'ComponentBlockerCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'componentBlocker',
            bindToController: true
        };
    });
```

that template:

```
<div class="component-blocker hc-ztop1002" ng-if="!componentBlocker.thisComponentIsLoaded">
    <!-- changed the following line from {{componentBlocker.animation}} -->
    <img src="{{componentBlocker.getLoadState()}}"/>
</div>
```

controller:

```
angular.module('myapp')
    .controller('ComponentBlockerCtrl', function ($scope, HC_EVENTS) {
        var ctrl = this;
        ctrl.thisComponentIsLoaded = false;
        $scope.$on(HC_EVENTS.componentLoaded, function () {
            ctrl.thisComponentIsLoaded = true;
            console.log('component is loaded = ' + ctrl.thisComponentIsLoaded);
        });
        // begin added code
        ctrl.getLoadState = function() {
            return ctrl.thisComponentIsLoaded;
        };
        // end added code
    });
```

the directive is called by

```
<hc-component-blocker animation="/images/spinner_black_16.gif"></hc-component-blocker>
```

The problem:

The `HC_EVENTS.componentLoaded` event is fired by the controller of a view that contains`<hc-component-blocker animation="/images/spinner_black_16.gif"></hc-component-blocker>`. It does this with this line of code:  `$scope.$broadcast(HC_EVENTS.componentLoaded);`

I know this is working because the console will tell me 'component is loaded = true'

However, nothing in the view updates. `ng-if="!componentBlocker.thisComponentIsLoaded"` should remove the entire element, but it remains in place. In addition, `{{componentBlocker.thisComponentIsLoaded}}` continues to display "false."

Why does the directive's template not update with the updated value of `componentBlocker.thisComponentIsLoaded`?

ETA: it appears to work properly with the expression. I wish to understand why a value doesn't work but an expression does. Is that by design?

Comment: Are you doing a `$digest` or a `$apply` after the `$broadcast`?

Comment: I am not explicitly doing a $digest or $apply, no.

Comment: what do you mean by expression?

Comment: What happens if you add the `animation` property to your `ComponentBlockerCtrl`? i.e. `this.animation = '';`